# bootstrap active tabs content on hover and go on external link on click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

all i need to do is to active bootstrap 3.3.4 tabs on hover on the nav tab and go to the link on link here is the example

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active">
<a href="http://google.com" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Home </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
<a href="http://yahoo.com" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> tab2 </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question. But if you want to add the active bootstrap class, then

```
class='active'
```

will do it. If you mean only on hover, you can either create your own similar class, such as

```
.notselected{
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.notselected:hover{
    background-color: #f1e5e5;
}
.selected{
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.selected:hover{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Then use jquery's toggleClass() function.

Comment: i want to change tabs on hover and go to link on click on the same <a> tag

Comment: Well, if you're not going to use my answer I can tell you now no other answers are coming. Also, this site isn't for requesting code, it's for help and  opinions.

Comment: i just ask for the possibility dear @Tobsta not asking for the code, my orignal problem is to target tabs panel on hover and target external links on click on the same nav. tab, my question's concern is not just styling